# I have a file location stored in a reach file. Like \reach. It thinks it is a carriage return

Tags: python

My file location is detecting the `\r` in `\reach` as a carriage return.
There is nothing I could find online about the topic. I need it to list the file location as only a string.

Comment: Can you provide any additional information? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use google and the common documentation for the topic before asking a question. In this case, you are looking for [that](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your string as a raw string by prefixing a `r`. A raw string ignores all backslashes.

```
location = r'\reach'
```

Alternatively you could use double backslashes like so

```
location = '\\reach'
```

A third way would be to just use forward slashes instead

```
location = '/reach'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be using windows as your os which uses '\' as separators.
You could try defining your file path in raw string. Eg.

f = open(r'dir1\dir2\reach')

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Didn't expect an r before the string would fix it but it did!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape slash with another slash in the string: `\\reach`